# Are rails controllers multithreaded? Thread.exclusive in controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading

Are Rails controllers multithreaded?

If so, can I protect a certain piece of code (which fires only once every ten minutes) from being run from multiple threads by simply doing

```
require 'thread'
Thread.exclusive do
     # stuff here
end
```

on do I need to somehow synchronize on a monitor?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Running `rake middleware` on a basic rails app gives the following:

```
use Rack::Lock
use ActionController::Failsafe
use ActionController::Reloader
use ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement
use ActiveRecord::QueryCache
use ActiveRecord::SessionStore, #<Proc:0x017fb394@(eval):8>
use ActionController::RewindableInput
use ActionController::ParamsParser
use Rack::MethodOverride
use Rack::Head
run ActionController::Dispatcher.new
```

The first item on the rack stack is [`Rack::Lock`](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/Rack/Lock.html). This puts a lock around each request, so only one request is handled at a time. As such a *standard* rails app is single threaded. You can however spawn new threads within a request that would make your app multi threaded, most people never encounter this.

If you are having issues…

```
require 'thread'
Thread.exclusive do
     # stuff here
end
```

… would ensure that stuff inside the block is never run in parallel with *any* other code. Creating a shared `Mutext` between all threads (in a class variable or something, but this could be wiped when reloaded in dev mode, so be careful), and locking on it as `Rack::Lock#call` does is to be preferred if you just want to ensure no two instances of the same code is executed at the same time.

Also, for the record, each request creates and dereferences one controller in each request cycle. No two requests should see the same instance, although they may see the same class.

Setting `config.threadsafe!` voids almost everything I said. That removes [`Rack::Lock`](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/Rack/Lock.html) from the stack, and means you will need to set a mutex manually to prevent double entry. Don't do it unless you have a really good reason.

Even without [`Rack::Lock`](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/Rack/Lock.html) you will still get one controller instance per request. The entry point to your controller ensures that, [notice the call to `new` in `process`.](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/a43ef2436cc6b63af35636127e42495ceb538cee/actionpack/lib/action_controller/base.rb#L381-392)

Comment: Could you address cwa's answer and this statement in the Mongrel FAQ, "While Rails is running there is only one controller in operation at a time." What does that mean, in operation at one time... that multiple threads are passed through a single instance like Java servlets?

Comment: BTW, I ended up synchronizing on a Mutex semaphore so my code is safe, no doubt, but I'd llike to understand this anyway. Thanks for your answer...

Comment: Rails is single threaded. Each request gets it's own controller instance, and only one thread is handled at a time.

Comment: Okay, sorry to keep going with this: so in a production environment you have "a pack of Mongrels," and one single-threaded controller instance at a time per Mongrel?

Comment: Correct. Many processes (mongrels), one thread per process (rails app).

Comment: Awesome, thank you again. And my last question... sorry to bother... would a $global Mutex semaphore be shared amongst all mongrel processes?

Comment: Nope, this would be for the single process only. To lock between processes you will need some inter-process flow control, on a single computer you can use file file locks, cross machine database locking (but that's another question entirely).

Comment: Is this still relevant for Rails 4?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that a new controller instance is created for each HTTP request that is processed by a controller.

Comment: Right, that would be exactly like a servlet.So then thread competition could be a problem with single-threaded resources.

Comment: Seems to be wrong, John. Could you verify it and correct your answer or delete it, please?

Comment: Why do you write that? Controller instance variables only exist for the lifetime of one request.

Comment: Sorry John, I'm trying to make sense of this. See the other answers. Citing something might help.

Comment: I could well be wrong. I'm sure I read somewhere that a new controller instance is created per request, but typically I can't find the reference now! And Googling this hasn't given much information.

Comment: Thanks John, it does in fact seem like you're right. It's also obvious now that I think about it. Otherwise you couldn't use @whatever variables as we are told to in Rails.

Comment: I just did a test in Rails 2.1. Controller instances are created per request.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby is single threaded. So at anytime, a controller can only handle one request at a time. If there are more than one requests, these requests are queued up. To avoid this, people usually run a small set of Mongrels to get good concurrency. It works like this(straight from Mongrel [WIKI FAQ](http://mongrel.rubyforge.org/wiki/FAQ)):

1. A request hits mongrel.
2. Mongrel makes a thread and parses the HTTP request headers
3. If the body is small, then it puts the body into a StringIO
4. If the body is large then it streams the body to a temp file
5. When the request is "cooked" it call the RailsHandler.
6. The RailsHandler sees if the file is possibly page cached, if so then it sends the cached page.
7. Now you're finally ready to process the Rails request. LOCK!
8. Still locked, Mongrel calls the Rails Dispatcher to handle the request, passing in the headers, and StringIO or Tempfile for body.
9. When Rails is done, UNLOCK! . Rails has (hopefully) put all of its output into a StringIO.
10. Mongrel then takes this StringIO output, any output headers, and streams them back to the client super fast.

    Notice that if there is no locking if the page is cached.

Comment: Ruby is not single-threaded. The GIL does not mean it's single-threaded.