# How to avoid race conditions when setting class variables on each request in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, race-condition, class-variables

I have an active resource like model that communicates with a restful resource.
The resource path has some dynamic parameters so I'm setting some class variables on the model before each request.

I have something like this:

```
class MyClass << MySuperClass::Base

  class << self
    attr_accessor :site
    attr_accessor :shop_id
    attr_accessor :product_id

    def get
      RestClient.get(self.site)
    end

    def set_site(shop_id, product_id)
      self.site = "http://example.com/api/shop/#{shop_id}/product/#{product_id}
    end
  end
end
```

In my application controller I have a before filter that sets the shop_id and product_id

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_site

  private

  def set_site
    MyClass.set_site(current_shop.id, current_product.id)
  end
end
```

As I understand from here: http://m.onkey.org/thread-safety-for-your-rails
This could be the cause of some race conditions.

That article was written 3 years ago so it is still the case that setting class variables per request could cause a race condition?

And if so then what is the current best practice to achieve similar behavior without incurring a race condition?

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388979/are-rails-controllers-multithreaded-thread-exclusive-in-controllers) says, "a standard rails app is single threaded." Check it for details.

Answer (score 0):

Don't set class variables for classes which will have different values for different requests.

Rails will persist class variables between requests and you won't be able to guarantee that data won't leak between two different users' sessions.