# Class methods in Rails, how do they work in terms of performance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, class, methods

I'm new in web programming and while I was following a Rails tutorial today I came up with a question I haven't found the answer on the Internet.

I've come to the conclusion that in Rails, for every new connection to the server, it creates new instance objects (controllers, models...) of the classes that I've declared for that connection but the question is in the called **class methods**.

I've read that in Ruby, static methods don't exist and they are methods of a singleton of the class but if there are 1 000 000 users requesting at the same time a Math operation (as `Math` has class methods) or some operation I have declared `def User.encrypt` for example, it's not supposed to be slower than if I call them on an object (an object for every single user) since all the 1 000 000 requests are "asked" to the same singleton object?

Saying that I come from learning OOP from Java and I've never programmed in Ruby may help to get a better answer :)

Thanks,

Comment: In Ruby, Classes are objects (i.e. instances of another class).  If you open irb and create a `Person` class `class Person; end` then you can see that `Person` is an instance of `Object` with `Person.ancestors`.  "Class methods" on `Person` are really just instance methods on the `Person` object.

Comment: @Powers Thanks for the answer, that gives me some more light in Ruby, but I was asking why if doing things this way, as instance methods of the `Person` object slow the server when 1 000 000 people at the same time call for the same method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Powers alluded to, in Ruby class methods are just instance methods on a class object--performance should be the same as an equivalent instance method.  In Rails specifically, many class methods are dynamically generated at runtime (for instance the `find_by_*` ActiveRecord methods), so performance of class methods can be somewhat unpredictable.

For the question of concurrent access to class methods, most Rails apps are single-threaded and so there will never be concurrent access to the same methods.  Scaling to many users in Rails typically involves adding more instances of the Rails app and putting them behind a load balancer, or using a multi-threaded server such as [Unicorn](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/) (which actually has separate Ruby environments for each thread).

Comment: Rails is not single threaded, the server you run it on (most likely) is. Rails has no trouble running concurrently (although in the default implementation of Ruby, "concurrently" isn't what you expect coming from Java or another truly concurrently language).

Comment: @LoganSerman So.. in ruby you can`t execute a method in another thread, is that what you mean?

Comment: You can, but MRI (the default implementation of Ruby) has something called the GVL (Global VM Lock) which prevents true concurrency. That explanation is not meant for just an SO comment - there are plenty of resources online if you wish to know more about it.

Comment: Good discussion of multi-threading in Rails: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388979/are-rails-controllers-multithreaded-thread-exclusive-in-controllers